# relative routes in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem calculating my routes.

This line works

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="<%=cRutaRelativa%><%=NOMBRE_PROYECTO%>/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

But, when I want to use a `file`:

```
Document doc = db.parse(cRutaRelativa + NOMBRE_PROYECTO  + "/Bhtcs/prueba.xml");
```

I have an `error`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\BKS_Platform\x64\eclipse\*cRutaRelativa + NOMBRE_PROYECTO*\Bhtcs\prueba.lit (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

How can I get access to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line gets **rendered into your HTML output** - so it will create a path *relative* to your context path that the client (the browser) will use to find the file.

Your second line accesses a file using a relative path. As you started your server in eclipse the base path for this operation resolves to your eclipse directory.

If you want your second line to find files relative to your context path as well, you could try it like this:

```
Document doc = db.parse(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
      + cRutaRelativa + NOMBRE_PROYECTO  + "/Bhtcs/prueba.xml");
```

Still this would require you to access the servlet context as well as relying on exploded war file and more stuff.

If your XML resides within your classpath (as it should), you are most likely better off accessing it as a resource with

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
      "/"+cRutaRelativa + NOMBRE_PROYECTO  + "/Bhtcs/prueba.xml");
```

However - your error is not for the XML file - it's for a ".lit" file. Is this maybe referenced from your `.xml` in some way?